# What is the relationship between cache coherence and memory barriers?

Tags: multithreading, assembly, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, memory-barriers

As far as I know, memory barriers are used to avoid [out-of-order execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution). However, memory barriers are often mentioned also when talking about cache coherence. I'm not sure how the two concepts are connected, since - according to my findings - cache coherence should already be guaranteed at a hardware level through various protocols, e.g. MESI and such. Is preventing out-of-order execution with memory barriers another way to (manually) grant cache coherence?

Comment: The simple answer, without getting into implementation details, is that the out-of-order CPU can access the cache in a order that's not the same as program order. The cache coherency protocol can't put those accesses back into program order, but memory barriers can stop them from being out of program order to begin with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On modern CPUs stores first go into a store buffer. When the store leaves the store buffer and is applied to the cache line only then the cache coherence protocol gets involved.

While the store is pending in the store buffer, the CPU which made the store can read it back from the store buffer (store-to-load forwarding), but other CPUs cannot observe the effects of the store just yet.

Memory barriers such as x86 [`MFENCE`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mfence) wait for the store buffer to drain:

> Performs a serializing operation on all load-from-memory and store-to-memory instructions that were issued prior the MFENCE instruction. This serializing operation guarantees that every load and store instruction that precedes the MFENCE instruction in program order becomes globally visible before any load or store instruction that follows the MFENCE instruction. The MFENCE instruction is ordered with respect to all load and store instructions, other MFENCE instructions, any LFENCE and SFENCE instructions, and any serializing instructions (such as the CPUID instruction). MFENCE does not serialize the instruction stream.

See [Memory Barriers: a Hardware View for Software Hackers](http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/scalability/paper/whymb.2010.07.23a.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Good first part, but `sfence` is not relevant.  `sfence` doesn't stop StoreLoad reordering, only StoreStore which is already prohibited by x86 in general except for NT stores.  `mfence` would be a better example: it stops later load instructions from reading cache until the store buffer drains.  `sfence` does not.  Notice that *It is not ordered with respect to memory loads*.  It doesn't block execution until the store-buffer drains, it only blocks commit of later stores until the store buffer drains.  You can think of it as setting up a "fence" in the store buffer that nothing can cross.

Comment: @PeterCordes You are quite right, `mfence` is the right example. Corrected.